# NHibernate Property Mapping, best practise for type attribute?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, mapping, properties, hbm

I have a little doubt for mapping of property in hbm file.

Sometimes I've mapped the string field of my db in this way:

```
<property name="MyPropName" column="MyColumnName" length="20" />
```

but the same mapping can be wrote in this way:

```
<property name="MyPropName" column="MyColumnName" type="String(20)" />
```

my question is...what's the better way?

If I omit "type" attributes for property tags it works, but I don't know if there are some contraindications. Can you tell me?

And last thing...are right this associations?

db varchar fields -> type "AnsiString"

db nvarchar fields -> type "String"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "best practice" is to only override the defaults. So, for your example, the first form would be the best.

As for the second question: yes, they are correct.

You can find all the value types and default mappings here: [5.2.2. Basic value types](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-types-basictypes)

Comment: Just a doubt...in terms of performance there are any difference from write or omit the "type" attribute? If I don't write the "type" attribute NHibernate get type by reflection, but I don't know if it does same thing also when the "type" is specified. Can you tell me?

Comment: Considering initialization happens just ONCE in your app lifetime, it really doesn't matter at all.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose that this inizialization has done when NHibernate build the configuration...right?